# Defining time window in Esper CEP pattern

Tags: esper

I have a CSV file containing time-stamped events, and I want to integrate the external time stamps in Esper pattern.
I know how to use the window ***ext_timed***.
For example this works:

```
select * from stream.win:_ext_timed(timestamps, 5 sec).
```

But I don't know how to use the external times inside patterns.
For example in the following query the engine internal time is used. I want to use external times with the ***within*** guard.

```
select * from pattern [ a=stream -> stream where timer:within(5 sec) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for advancing time is in [1].
The EsperIO CSV adapter does pretty much the same thing that you are planning to do and you could look at its source code. It will use the same API [1].

[1] http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#api-controlling-time

Comment: Many thanks, this API is much better and contains everything I want.